# Bind different maps using guice

Tags: binding, guice

I have a map in my file like:

```
workflowProperties1 = { "key1" : "value1"; "key2": "value2"; };

workflowProperties2 = { "key1" : "value1"; "key2": "value2"; };
```

I want to inject this map in a constructor of a class using guice. I am doing something like:

```
@Inject public myClass(@Named("workflowProperties1") Map<String,String> someMap) { }
```

Can some one suggest how I inject one of the two maps (workflowProperties1 or workflowProperties2) in myClass above based on a static parameter value?

Comment: What's the file that has the map definitions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution might be to use [Guice Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings). Please note that the multibinders are not included in the core Guice so you will need an extra dependency to `com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings`.

Then you may define your binding module, something like this (in reality you will extract the key/value-s from your file):

```
@Override
protected void configure()
{
    MapBinder<String, String> wf1Binder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
                    binder(), 
                    String.class, 
                    String.class, Names.named("workflowProperties1"));

    wf1Binder.addBinding("WF1Key").toInstance("WF1Value");

    MapBinder<String, String> wf2Binder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
                    binder(), 
                    String.class, 
                    String.class, Names.named("workflowProperties2"));

    wf2Binder.addBinding("WF2Key").toInstance("WF2Value");
}
```

Then you can easily inject the right map "based on a static parameter value" as you asked e.g:

```
private static final String STATIC_PARAMETER_VALUE = "workflowProperties1";

@Inject
@Named(STATIC_PARAMETER_VALUE) 
Map<String,String> someMap;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a concrete class

```
public class WorkFlowProperties {

  Map<String, String> someMap;

  public Map<String, String> getSomeMap() {
    return someMap;
  }

  public void setSomeMap(Map<String, String> someMap) {
    this.someMap = someMap;
  }
}
```

Within your ApplicationModule

```
ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {

...

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Map.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("workflowProperties1")).to(workFlowProperties1.getSomeMap());
    bind(Map.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("workflowProperties2")).to(workFlowProperties2.getSomeMap());
  }
}
```

where `workFlowProperties2` and `workFlowProperties2` are instances of `WorkFlowProperties` that can be configured using the `.yml` config or any other binding.

Comment: Should it be bounded with method "toInstance()" rather than "to()" ? "to()" function is expecting a Class type